# How to calculate integral of density under constraint?

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, mathematical-statistics, bivariate, constraint

Given a bivariate standard-normally distributed random variable $Y=[Y_1,Y_2]^T$ with density $\phi(Y_i,Y_2)$, the probability of $Y_1>0$ is simply $$P(Y_1 > 0)=1- \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{0} \phi(y_i,y_2) dy_1dy_2=\frac{1}{2}.$$
I try to find the integral of $\phi(Y_i,Y_2)$ under the constraint $Y_1+Y_2 \ge 0$, that is $P(Y_1+Y_2 \ge 0)$. How should I define the integral and integrate the bivariate density?

Comment: Could you first consider whether or not you can directly derive the distribution of $Y_1+Y_2$?

Comment: Useful. Seems one can sum (e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables) and then apply the integral given above on the distribution of the sum?

Comment: Not the integral above since it then is a unidimensional integral...

Comment: $y_1$ can take on any value in $\mathbb{R}$ but $y_2$ can be at most $-y_1$.  This should help you set up the integral.